# Vaadin textfield does not show Chinese characters

Tags: unicode, textfield, vaadin

I have a web application that uses Vaadin and I have forms with Vaadin TextField's. If you enter Chinese characters into the textfield they appear not to be handled properly by Vaadin. In the debugger when storing "(String)usernameField.getValue()" I see the Chinese characters are not understood. This happens in an English Windows and in a Simplified Chinese Windows 7 VM (for the web client, the server is in an English Windows PC). Is this a limitation of Vaadin or do I need to call special methods in the TextField class or configure it somehow. I have not seen any clues in the TextField API.

Comment: I think you have some charset mapping problem. Vaadin should work with all UTF-8 characters...
It would be better to ask this in the vaadin forum

Comment: Have done that. Have asked in the vaadin forum

Comment: It would be nice if you can post the URL to the forum post.

Comment: Here it is https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3627866 However it is unanswered although it is one week old. Seems unlikely it will be answered.

Comment: Well, after a few days have passed, I have discovered that Vaadin is working properly. The debugger did not show the characters because the font used did not include them. The database where the business objects are persisted needs to support Unicode too.

Answer (score 0):

See my last comment. Vaadin works properly with Unicode characters. Must make sure the debugger font and the database also do.